# Error In getting campaign group by ID using linkedin api

Tags: python, rest, linkedin-api

When making a get request to linkedin api to search by campaign group value I get ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT error.

`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAccounts/{{accountID}/adCampaignGroups?q=search&search=(id:(values:List(urn:li:sponsoredCampaignGroup:{{campaign_group_id}}))"`

I tried to make get request to the api.

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.linkedin.com/rest/adAccounts/{{accountID}/adCampaignGroups?q=search&search=(id:(values:List(urn:li:sponsoredCampaignGroup:{{campaign_group_id}}))"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'LinkedIn-Version': '202401',
  'X-RestLi-Protocol-Version': '2.0.0',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer {{token}}',
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

```json
{
    "status": 400,
    "code": "ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT",
    "message": "Invalid query parameters passed to request"
}
```